# Winget Uninstall outdate node.js version failed

Tags: node.js, windows-10, uninstallation, winget

I try to uninstall Node.js version 15.14.0 with winget uninstall by id.
winget returns
'Es wurde kein installiertes Paket gefunden, das den Eingabekriterien entspricht.'
what means no inst. package of the criteria found. I am on a windows 10 (german) withwindows terminal/ powershell 7.3.10.
When I list the node.js packages with winget ls -q node it comes back with

```
Node.js {C6D70F34-C254-4D55-B4A0-55F921939297} 15.14.0
Node.js {C9581A3B-99C4-474C-9592-DA64BA42A02D} 21.3.0
```

The question is why is winget not able to uninstall even if the package is known to winget ?

I could not find node.js in Windows Programm and features add or delete.
I installed the latest node.js with an msi installer package to 21.3.0
This node.js is than also avalable under windows program and features add or delete